# MySQL Joining multiple select satement containing multiple values for View

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, join, view, subquery

I have a Table having all IN detail

```
+----------+------------+-----------+
| staff_id | date       | time      | 
+----------+------------+-----------+
|    1     | 2015-02-20 |    07:00  |  
|    2     | 2015-02-20 |    07:01  |  
|    3     | 2015-02-20 |    07:05  |  
|    1     | 2015-02-20 |    07:02  |  
|    1     | 2015-02-20 |    07:04  |  
+----------+--------------+---------+
```

another Table having all OUT detail

```
+----------+------------+-----------+
| staff_id | date       | time      | 
+----------+------------+-----------+
|    1     | 2015-02-20 |    13:00  |  
|    2     | 2015-02-20 |    13:45  |  
|    3     | 2015-02-20 |    13:45  |  
|    1     | 2015-02-20 |    13:47  |  
|    1     | 2015-02-20 |    13:48  |  
+----------+--------------+---------+
```

What required result is
Time In, min val and Time Out, max value

```
+----------+------------+-----------+
| staff_id | date       | time IN   | Time Out
+----------+------------+-----------+
|    1     | 2015-02-20 |    07:00  | 13:48
|    2     | 2015-02-20 |    07:01  | 13:45
```

What Im doing is

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT sai.staff_id AS staff_id_in,
          sai.date AS date_in,
          sai.time AS time_in,
          sai.ip4 AS ip4_in,
          sai.location_id AS location_id_in,
          '1' AS atd_in
   FROM staff_attendance_in sai
   ORDER BY staff_id ASC, time ASC) AS sub
GROUP BY staff_id_in,
         date_in
UNION
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT sao.staff_id AS staff_id_out,
          sao.date AS date_out,
          sao.time AS time_out,
          sao.ip4 AS ip4_out,
          sao.location_id AS location_id_out,
          '2' AS atd_out
   FROM staff_attendance_out sao
   ORDER BY time DESC) AS sub
GROUP BY staff_id_out,
         date_out
```

but I am not able to generate view from the query... neither join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
SELECT I.staff_id, I.date, MIN(I.time_IN), MAX(O.Time Out)
FROM IN I JOIN OUT O
ON I.staff_id = O.staff_id
GROUP BY I.staff_id, I.date;
```

I think this can help you.

Comment: This query
SELECT I.staff_id, I.date, MIN(I.time) as time_in, MAX(O.Time) as time_out FROM staff_attendance_in I JOIN staff_attendance_out O ON I.staff_id = O.staff_id GROUP BY I.staff_id, I.date
is generating result this
1     2015-02-19      7:00       13:02
1     2015-02-20      7:02        13:02

getting same time value in all ...

Comment: Wat are you trying to say??

Comment: Bajpal
This is working...
SELECT I.staff_id, I.date, MIN(I.time) as time_in, MAX(O.Time) as time_out FROM staff_attendance_in I JOIN staff_attendance_out O ON I.staff_id = O.staff_id where I.date = O.date GROUP BY I.staff_id, I.date